# A question about an assertion in Ahlfors.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f(z)=u+iv $. Ahlors (pg. 25) says that if $f$ is analytic, then so are $u$ and $v$.

Using the fact that $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$, we get

> $$\Delta u:=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

I don't understand how this follows from the aforementioned facts.

Comment: Ahlfors states that $\Delta u =0$, where $\Delta u = u_{xx}+u_{yy}$ *by definition*.

Comment: @Siminore- Point taken. That is the definition of $\Delta u$. But why is this relation satisfied for $u$ and $v$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the book says the if $f$ is analytic then $u$ and $v$ are *harmonic*. Anyway, you have:
$$u_x=v_y\qquad u_y=-v_x\ .$$
Now derive w.r.t. $x$ the first equation and w.r.t. to $y$ the second:
$$u_{xx}=v_{xy}\qquad u_{yy}=-v_{xy}\ .$$
If you sum the two equation you get
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0\ .$$
Deriving w.r.t. $y$ the first equation and w.r.t. to $x$ the second, you obtain the same equation for $v$ by taking the difference.